# How many possible combinations in 9 character?

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

I have a question because i cant solve it myself i dont realy know how to calculate it exactly, i know it's gonna be easy for you in this section..

So i have 2 questions,
I want my computer to generate all possibility of 9 character, with: only uppercase alphabetic, and number
so exemple:
A5S8E5D8E5

How many possibility is possible ? , no lower case, only uppercase and number.

And if its possible to know, how many time it would take to guess all possibility ?
I know it depend of the configuration of my computer but well let's say a 1080 GTX.

Thank for your help guys !

Comment: Why the tags "complex-analysis" and "statistics" ?

Comment: @TheSilverDoe sorry it's clearly the wrong tags, but i wasn't able to put any tags due to my reputation

Comment: Are you familiar with Pascal's Triangle.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle.

Answer (score 2):

So you have 26 possibilities for upper-case letters and 10 possibilities for digits meaning you have 36 possibilities for each character. In total you obtain that number:

$$
36^9 \simeq 10^{14}
$$

To see how long it would take for a GPU to crack it, we would need to test the hash of a password and compare it to the hash stored in the database. So it depends on the algorithm you use to produce the hash and check in the database. To get an idea, from this [website](https://improsec.com/tech-blog/mind-blowing-gpu-performance) (for MD5 encryption), we get that a GTX 1080 processes $4 \times 10^{10}$ hashes per second. So you get a rough estimate of $2500s$ which is less than an hour.

Note that it blows up if you use all possibilities from your keyboard.You get 10 digits + 26 lowercase + 26 uppercase + 31 special characters which is 93. Then the numbers of possibilities gets to $10^{17}$ and it takes roughly 1 month non-stop to exhaust all possibilities.

Comment: Oh great.. so what i understand is, with 26 uppercase+10 number possibility, it would take 41 minutes for a 1080 GTX to get all possibility of 9 characters ? thank it helped me a lot !

Comment: I think so yes unless I made a mistake. It seemed surprising to me at 1st too but I think this is right. Note that depends a lot on the encryption scheme used (though MD5 is quite standard).

Comment: mmh interesting, I thought much more as you know! But it depends if you have access to 'raw' database at the end , right?

Comment: Right. But then if you don't have access to it there is not much you can do.

Answer (score 1):

For each character, you have $26$ letters + $10$ digits = $36$ possible choices.
Therefore, the total number of combinations is $36^9$, which is a really big number.

I'm not sure about computation time though, since I'm not a hardware expert.

Comment: Alright so it would be 101 559 956 668 416 attempt right ? well yes that's a big number, thank

Comment: Are you trying to bash a password or something?

Comment: @GeneralPoxter It's not for a password, but something for a algorithm

Comment: @Tortar no I think it takes less an hour for the GPU he mentioned. For a CPU it would take more time yes. Cf my answer

Answer (score 1):

This problem is called a permutation with repetition. The sequence here involves 26 letters of the English alphabet and 10 numbers from 0 to 9.

This turns out to be a simple calculation. So we can form a sequence of 9 characters by selecting one letter/number out of 36 for each character, which gives us:

$$36 \times 36 \times 36\times 36\times 36\times 36\times 36\times 36\times 36 = 36^9 = 101559956668416 \simeq 10^{14} $$

To estimate the total time required you need to know the execution time of your algorithm needed for testing a sequence of 9 characters, then you multiply by $36^9$ times.

Comment: Are you sure that upper and lower doesn't matter ? 
Because if its only uppercase, there will be less possibility than upper and lower right ?
What i mean is like, lets do it for 1 character :
AaBbCc ect..
then if its only upper its:
ABC ect..

So less guessing no ?

Comment: I meant we have 26 letters in total, and the number of letters doesn't change if the letters are uppercase or lowercase. However, if you decide to combine them, you have double this number in terms of possibilities (26 + 26 for each character). I removed the confusing part in my answer.

Comment: Oh yes alright i get it now, thank man !